# Changing thousands separators from comma to space in measured grids of ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, grids-graticules

In ArcMap it is easy to include commas as thousands separators on a measured grid, as can be seen in the screenshot below, but I have not been able to find a way to change the separator used from being a comma to a **space** instead.

There does not seem to be an Advanced ArcMap Setting to do it, and I have looked for, and not found, an ArcGIS Idea for this either.

Is there a way to do it that I am overlooking?

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The solution to this is not in ArcGIS.  Unfortunatly, you have to change your region settings in Windows.  On Windows 7, the solution is to go to Control Panel, Region and Language, then click on Additional settings...

[image]

Under Digit Grouping Symbol, just type in a space instead of a comma.

[image]

Results:
[image]