# How to permanently change Arcmap table display?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-table

At Arc 10.0 I can configure the properties of an Arcmap numeric table field using its Field Properties > Numeric... > and then clicking the "Show thousands separators" checkbox on.

But I would like to make that setting permanent (i.e. always show thousands separators) for every numeric field, across every table, for every map document, forever.

This doesn't appear in the Arcmap Options, nor in AdvancedArcMapSettings.exe.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think you may be [dreaming](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dik_wnOE4dk).  As an example, see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164245/changing-thousands-separators-from-comma-to-space-in-measured-grids-of-arcmap I think this is one of those things that sounds like it should be easy for the ArcGIS Desktop development team to sort but to do so would be a very major project that could introduce new bugs.  I would look for this in ArcGIS Pro - not ArcMap.

Comment: @PolyGeo Tell 'im 'e's dreamin'    LOL

Answer (score 1):

This is a known limitation within ArcGIS from what I can recall and is not possible to do. Not aware of any workarounds and I cannot test this myself at the moment, but would exporting your data with these settings to a .lyr file work if you pulled in that file in every document?