# Showing thousands separator in row count at bottom of ArcMap tables?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, arcgis-10.4

Using Arcmap 10.4.1 is it possible to add thousands separators (such as commas) to the numbers (selected and total) of table records displayed at the bottom of each table display?  I think that readability would be greatly enhanced!

I know how to add thousands separators to the numeric values within the table by right-clicking the field name and modifying its properties, but here I'm interested in the totals displayed at the bottom of each table.

I've looked in the ArcMap Options dropdown, but... nothing.  I would like to make this the default feature.  Any thoughts?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that Windows settings do not help like they did in [Changing thousands separators from comma to space in measured grids of ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164245), if you want this enhancement to be implemented I think you will need to submit an [ArcGIS Idea](https://geonet.esri.com/community/arcgis-ideas/).

My recommendation would be to submit it for the newer architecture of ArcGIS Pro rather than ArcMap.